# Casting from Any to Double swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, casting

I have a simple question, I have this dictionary:

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["Area": "100", "YessorNo" : true]
```

And, for the key `area`, I want to cast it's value to a `double`, like so:

```
let a = dict["Area"] as? Double
```

When I print `a`, I get a `nil`, why? the value `100` is although a `string` but it is a number isn't? why can't I cast it to a `double`?

Comment: *"but it is a number isn't?"* – No. It is a string.

Comment: @BrendonCheung Your dictionary type is any that means it can store any type of value. That don't allow to mixup value types. String stored in Any will always cast as string only not Double or any other classes

Answer (score 9):

You can't directly cast a `String` to a `Double`, you need to use the proper initializer.

```
guard let numStr = dict["Area"] as? String else {
    return
}
let a = Double(numStr)
```

Comment: Thank, so it is impossible to directly cast a `Any` or `AnyObject` to a `double`? why is that?

Comment: a cast is just a way to tell the compiler to shut up and treat the value as a certain type. It does not convert that value into the enforced type. If a value, typed any, actually holds an double, than you can cast it. but if it holds an string, that will not be possible, as strings and doubles are very different things.

Comment: You can only cast types that are related. You can cast `Any` to `String` because a `String` is an `Any` (and so is a `Double`). But a `String` is not a `Double`.

Answer (score 4):

First, cast from Any to String, and then use an initializer to convert it to Double.

```
if let a = dict["Area"] as? String, let aDouble = Double(a) {
    print(aDouble)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers provided the code, I will focus on the why of the question.  Type casting won't work because, according to the Swift docs, type casting allows you to "treat that instance as a different superclass or subclass from somewhere else in its own class hierarchy."  Since a double is not a subclass or a superclass of a string, you can't cast a string to a double even if that string is a string of a number.  This is why trying to cast a string to a double returns nil.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! but I have seen coders `AnyObject` to `Double` before, like this: https://github.com/carambalabs/DarkSkyKit/blob/master/DarkSkyKit/Models/ForecastDataPoint.swift

Comment: Under the `map` function, they have a dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]` and directly cast `AnyObject` to a `Double`

Comment: Yes, AnyObject can be cast to a Double, if the underlying type is Double.  In the code you posted.  Yes, data["time"] as? Double works, but the underlying dictionary must look like this ["time" : 25.0 ].  It can't look like this ["time" : "25"].

Comment: Okay, gotcha, but according to Apple: Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.
AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type. Howcome casting AnyObject to a struct is possible?

Comment: The as operator performs type casting and checks for protocol performance.  So, I believe that AnyObject as Struct, for example, would be a protocol conformance check, but I'll be interested to check into it more.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID283

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie, you're seriously down-voting me for providing some additional clarification that the question asked appreciated, which you can see from the comments. Give me a break!

Comment: I'm sorry. If you edit the answer, it will give me the ability to change my vote. Do that if you wish, and let me know so that I can upvote it.